Does $B\setminus A$ contain non-empty open set?
Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty bounded, connected open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose $A\subsetneq B$. Is it always true that $B\setminus A$ contain non-empty open set? What I have so far is as follows: Suppose $B\setminus A$ does not contain non-empty open set. Then we can show that $B$ is contained in the closure of $A$. But I can't get a contradiction from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Let $B$ be an open ball of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with center $(0, 0)$, and let $A$ be $B\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.
